# How to use the different fonts available for LaTeX -- miktex (23.1) on a windows 10 platform?

Tags: fonts, miktex

I feel exhausted and frustrated from trying to use some of the fonts from: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ , e.g. Calligraphical and Handwritten Fonts, Other (mostly decorative) Fonts, etc. I have tried many of the comments/suggestions from tex.stackexchange.com and I still fail :-(. I have carefully examined the log files but nothing I saw in them was the "key" to solving the problems associated with the LaTeX code. I have been using LaTeX for over 40 years and thought I could find at least one possible solution; but, now I must stop working on this.

Please, I beg of you, take a close look at why there are so many font problems being reported with miktex  22, 23 and see if there is a fix that really works.

I am using **miktex 4.9 console** in the administrator mode. I have reinstalled miktex at least 7 times by now -- still font problems. The following is taken from the **System Report.txt** file generated by TeXstudio 4.5.1 (git 4.5.1) Using Qt Version 6.4.2, compiled with Qt 6.4.2 RTeXstudio (4.5.1):

dpi: 96
where pdflatex: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe

PDFLATEX: pdflatex.exe -version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.14 (MiKTeX 23.1)

I will prepare an example that should be helpful in finding the problems associated with "special" fonts in TeXstudio.

> ***How can I upload the tex file for this example to be prepared?***

Comment: every font that says "open type or ttf only" is only for xelatex/luatex. If the description mention only type1 fonts it is for pdflatex. I have no idea what miktex 4.9. should be, my miktex has version 23.1 (and its pdftex has version 4.14). If you want help, you should show a complete, small example what you are trying and the log-file of the compilation.

Comment: The best practice in these case is usually to reinstall the MikTeX contribution. As Ulrike mentioned: *there is no MikTeX version 4.9.x*. So I suggest to visit [the site of MikTeX](https://miktex.org/download) and download a fresh distribution file.

Comment: I tried adding comment(s) but was never able to post it

Answer (score 2):

I will take the wild guess that since you have been using TeX for 40 years, you are still trying to do things the ancient way.

Can you compile with `lualatex`? Yes, it's in MiKTeX. You text must be utf-8 encoded (I believe even Windows does that, nowadays). Your fonts must be `*.otf` or `*.ttf` but NOT the old Type 1 PostScript fonts. They do not need to come from TeX (even system fonts will work). Try this, compiled with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Your Favorite Font} % Actual font name.
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

Now, some TeX fonts are not available as `*.otf` or `*.ttf`. In this case, you can use the `FontForge` program to import the existing font format, and convert it to `*.otf` (Open Type).

BIG EDIT:
I can get Starburst to work. Do these things:

1. Download the `initials` zip package directly from CTAN. Unzip it
   in your home directory (not within TeX).
2. Install FontForge. Open file `Starburst.pfb` in FontForge.
3. FontForge Menu Encoding > Reencode > Unicode (BMP).
4. Edit > Select > Select All.
5. Element > Correct Direction.
6. Hints > Clear Hints.
7. Element > Overlap > Remove Overlap.
8. Element > Font Info > PS Private > New > BlueValues
9. File > Generate Fonts > choose OpenType (CFF).

You will get a dialog box informing you that there are missing extrema,
wrong direction, self-intersection. Ignore that, and generate the font.
The messages are meaningful, but not worth fixing without expertise.

Then you will have Starburst.otf. It is an OpenType font.

In a place such as your TEXMFHOME directory, create fonts/opentype/initials
and drop a copy of Starburst.otf in there. Then refresh the files
(MiKTeX has a button to press, Linux uses command `mktexlsr`).

Do not `\usepackage{initials}` or `starburst` or anything of the sort.
Instead, compile with lualatex, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % or whatever
\newfontface\shazam{Starburst}
\begin{document}
{\shazam Hello World !}\par
And hello to Martians, too.\par
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Ok @rallg,
Your procedure for using FontForge, although rather complex, worked and the following Latex code worked with Texstudio and Texmaker :-).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lucida Sans} % or whatever
\newfontface\shazam{Starburst-Regular}
\begin{document}
{\shazam Hello World !}\par
And hello to Martians, too.\par
\end{document}
```

I still can not understand how to add a comment on someone else's comment. Example, if I hit a CR (carriage return) for a new line, then my comment on their comment is posted -- this is not what should happen IMHO!

Comment: Your comments were very useful @rallg. Yes, I can compile with LuaLaTeX (Texmaker 5.1.3) and I used your short example with: ```\setmainfont{QTCaslan}```, compiled with LuaLaTeX and this worked fine :-). However, when I tried the Starburst Regular fonts (Type 1) this failed with both LaTeX (Texstudio) and LuaLaTex (Texmaker). **How can I get the latex code to you?**

Comment: Thanks for the tip on **FontForge**

Comment: @Birdy See the "big edit" to my original answer. Detailed explanation of what works for me, and should work for you.

Comment: @Birdy Happy to hear that it worked. Now, all those FontForge steps are not necessarily needed. In many cases, it is enough to open the `*.pfb` file, then immediately generate the Open Type CFF font. But I echoed the steps I took, out of force of habit.

Answer (score 1):

run in a terminal the command `luafindfont`  and you'll get the complete list of fonts which can be used by the different latex engines. Fonts in the directory `.../opentype/`. or `.../truetype/` or in a system directory can only be used with `lualatex/xelatex` and all other by `pdflatex` :

```
bash-5.2$ luafindfont -n "*"
  No.                                            Filename                                                                                   Path
   1.                                Aboensis-Regular.otf                     /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/aboensis/
   2.                                     academicons.ttf                  /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/academicons/
   3.                      Academy Engraved LET Fonts.ttf                                                    /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/
   4.                                 ACaslonPro-Bold.otf                                                      /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Caslon/
   5.                           ACaslonPro-BoldItalic.otf                                                      /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Caslon/
   6.                               ACaslonPro-Italic.otf                                                      /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/Caslon/
   ....
   ....
6644.            ヒラギノ角ゴシック W9.ttc                                                                 /System/Library/Fonts/
6645.            ヒラギノ角ゴシック W9.ttc                                                                 /System/Library/Fonts/
6646.                                      儷宋_Pro.ttf                                                   /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/KozukaPro/
6647.                                    华文仿宋.ttf                                                   /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/KozukaPro/
6648.                                    华文楷体.ttf                                                   /Users/voss/Library/Fonts/KozukaPro/
```